# Regex to accept only variable names

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I write a regex that accepts only words or letters and split them by `,`?

I have tried `array = input.replace(/ /g, '').split(',')`, but then `h-e,a<y` will become `['h-e','a<y']` I want to accept only variables, so I guess `h-e,a<y` should become `['he','ay']`.

Would it be something like

```
array = input.replace(/[\s|^\w]/g, '').split(',')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "words" and "letters"? Your title refers to "variable names"--do you mean JavaScript variable names? They can include dollar signs and underscores which are not "letters". You talk about "accepting", but the description of your problem seems to be about "converting". Please clarify, thanks.

Comment: I am sorry. I mean just words (including 1-character words, which is what I meant by letters)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex to find all the characters that you want to remove from your string:

```
array = input.replace(/[-><?.:;]*/ig, '').split(',')
```

You will replace all the characters that are inside the [ ].

Comment: But I don't know exactly which characters the use might input. I just want to make sure that I get words (including 1-character words)

Comment: I thought you will need to find a pattern for the variable names because you could have this situation: my-var-other-number .. what could result in my-var - other-number or my-var-other - number. So if you have the spaces between the variables will be perfect if not, I think you has to think in other way because this one is not possible. For example finding in all the file variable per variable. so if you find my-var 4 times, means that's the name, right?

Answer (score 0):

Split first, then remove characters not allowed:

```
input.split(,).map(fix)
```

where

```
function fix(s) {
  return s.replace(/[^\w$]/g, '');
}
```

Another approach is to grab the characters you want, instead of throwing away the ones you don't:

```
function fix(s) {
  return s.match(/[\w$]/g).join('');
}
```

Actually, this is not exactly right, because JavaScript variable names can also contain Unicode characters such as Σ. Also, this would not fix up leading numeric characters, which JavaScript variable names cannot start with.